# Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals

Tags: matlab

i have the following error in my matlab function code:

??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in ==> AFA at 15
    M(k,j) = mean(T(i:sze,j));

here is the part of the code where the problem is  :

```
sz =size(T);
lim = sz(2) - ordre;
M = zeros(sz(1),sz(2));
r= 0;
for j=1:sze,
    k = 1;
for i=1:lim,
    M(k,j) = mean(T(i:i+ordre,j));
    k = k + 1;    
end

for i=lim+1:sz(2),
    M(k,j) = mean(T(i:sz(2),j));
    k = k + 1; 
end
end
```

Comment: Sounds like `ordre` is zero, then `lim+1 > sz(2)`. Just a guess...

Comment: no, actually ordre=5 at this point

Comment: Can matlab print data to the screen or a log file?  Could you have it print the state of all variables before that function call, and then review the log to see what index it's complaining about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me without error

```
T = magic(25);ordre = 5; %# I make up some values here
sz =size(T);
lim = sz(2) - ordre;
%# I've added a check here
if lim < 1, error('ordre has to be at most sz(2)-1 (is %i)',ordre);end
M = zeros(sz(1),sz(2));
r= 0;
for j=1:sz(2), %# I needed to change this line (sz(1) works as well)
    k = 1;
for i=1:lim,
    M(k,j) = mean(T(i:i+ordre,j));
    k = k + 1;    
end

for i=lim+1:sz(2),
    M(k,j) = mean(T(i:sz(2),j));
    k = k + 1; 
end
```

end

Comment: yes instead of putting sz(1) in the line you modified try to put sz(2), because in my case sze = sz(2).

Comment: @TarikMokafih: Everything works with `sz(2)` as well. What size is `T`?

Comment: i just tried with yours and it's working but when T is the input matrix i'm passing to the function it dosn't work ( T is an integer matrix of size : 100*4)

Comment: @TarikMokafih: Since your array has four columns, and `ordre` is 5, `lim` is `-1`, and `i` in the final loop starts out at 0.

Comment: @TarikMokafih: see my new version